# Magento 2 - How to disable access Rest API Default

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

How to disable access permission Rest API default?
Such as I can view all product attribute information by: http://localhost/magento/rest/V1/products/attributes/status

```
{
    "is_wysiwyg_enabled": false,
    "is_html_allowed_on_front": false,
    "used_for_sort_by": false,
    "is_filterable": false,
    "is_filterable_in_search": false,
    "is_used_in_grid": false,
    "is_visible_in_grid": false,
    "is_filterable_in_grid": false,
    "position": 0,
    "apply_to": [],
    "is_searchable": "1",
    "is_visible_in_advanced_search": "0",
    "is_comparable": "0",
    "is_used_for_promo_rules": "0",
    "is_visible_on_front": "0",
    "used_in_product_listing": "1",
    "is_visible": true,
    "scope": "website",
    "attribute_id": 94,
    "attribute_code": "status",
    "frontend_input": "select",
    "entity_type_id": "4",
    "is_required": false,
    "options": [
        {
            "label": "Enabled",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "label": "Disabled",
            "value": "2"
        }
    ],
    "is_user_defined": false,
    "default_frontend_label": "Status",
    "frontend_labels": null,
    "backend_type": "int",
    "source_model": "Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Attribute\\Source\\Status",
    "default_value": "1",
    "is_unique": "0",
    "validation_rules": []
}
```

Comment: Do you want to prohibit anonymous access to http://localhost/magento/rest/V1/products/attributes/status ?

Comment: Yes! @ Alex Paliarush

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is available since [Magento 2.0.4](https://github.com/magento/magento2/releases/tag/2.0.4) and is provided by [WebapiSecurity](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/app/code/Magento/WebapiSecurity) module. It makes product, website and CMS web APIs restricted to admin users by default. However you can still make them anonymous using configuration in the admin panel.